# Office add-in development: VSTO or web-based app using Napa?

Tags: .net, outlook, vsto, office-addins

My company has a plan to develop an add-in for Outlook that can interact with our web-based internal ERP application or our database to retrieve and update data.

I have done some studies on this topic and found that there're 2 approaches available:

1. Using **Visual Studio Tools for Office (VSTO)** that can leverage .NET language such as C# to develop an add-in that can be installed to local computer like an assembly.
2. Develop **a web-based application using Napa or Visual Studio**: this kind of add-in can run on both Outlook desktop and web application as well as can be published to Office store.

But I am still confused of the pros and cons of each approach and have not decided yet. Does anybody have experience on this and give me some advice? Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think it comes down to how much of the Outlook Object Model you need to access. If your software needs to leverage a wide selection of internal Outlook functions, VSTO is the only way to go. Web Add-ins have less access to internal Outlook functionality, but are ideal for applications accessing selective Outlook functionality and other functionality and data outside of Outlook.

Comment: I see and will consider it, thank you! :-)

Comment: VSTO is working desktop version of Outlook and web-based application using Nepa or visual studio has limited function and work for limited version of outlook. web-based application it xml based addin . If you need any help let me contact. I have already developed more than 100 of outlook plugins

Comment: hei shyam i want to to develop one webbased outlook add-in .Have u any example `?

Comment: @Shyamsundarshah Will the add-in developed using VSTO work on outlook web as well?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It depends on your goals - what exactly you need to implement in Outlook. I'd suggest starting from the [Selecting an API or technology for developing solutions for Outlook](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj900714.aspx) article. Mail Apps API is still very limited.

Comment: Thank you! This is what I am looking for.